# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, tomcat

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto que utiliza la librería `Prosys-OPC-UA-Java-SDK-Client-Binary-2.2.6-708` (es un cliente opc-ua). Dicha librería tiene una serie de dependencias:

- 'Opc.Ua.Stack-1.02.336.8'
- 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52'
- 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.52'
- 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
- 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
- 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
- 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
- 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:4.3.3'

Cuando intento desplegar mi proyecto sobre Tomcat, el servidor lanza el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:58)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.ContainerInitializer.onStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 46 more
```

Por lo que he leido, la dependencia `slf4j-api` requiere una implementación. En mi caso le proporciono la implementación de `slf4j-log4j12`. A continuación presento las dependencias del fichero `build.gradle` del proyecto:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.3.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.2.3.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.2.3.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final-redhat-1'

    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0.1'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.35'

    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4'

    compile group: 'commons-digester', name: 'commons-digester', version: '2.1'

    compile group: 'com.lowagie', name: 'itext', version: '4.2.1'

    compile group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '5.1.0'
    compile group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports-fonts', version: '5.6.1'

    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml-schemas', version: '3.7'

    compile name: 'bcprov-jdk16-146'
    // Librerías para la versión 2.2.6-708 de prosys
    compile name: 'Opc.Ua.Stack-1.02.336.8'
    compile name: 'Prosys-OPC-UA-Java-SDK-Client-Binary-2.2.6-708'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.52'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:4.3.3'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile name: 'sc-core-1.52.0.0'
    compile name: 'scpkix-1.52.0.0'
    compile name: 'scprov-1.52.0.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile(group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.1.0') {
        exclude(module: 'c3p0')
    }
    compile group: 'net.objecthunter', name: 'exp4j', version: '0.4.3.BETA-3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.187'
}
```

Estoy utilizando la versión **8.0.32** de tomcat.

Comment: Porque no utilizas esta implementación  **slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar** esta si trae la clase **LoggerFactory**. Y la que tu estas utilizando trae la clase **Log4jLoggerFactory**.

Comment: Porque dependo de la librería Prosys-OPC-UA-Java-SDK-Client-Binary-2.2.6-708, que requiere las dependencias indicadas.

Comment: Puedes excluir dependencias de una librería para que puedas agregar la versión de la librería que quieras. Esto es, asumes (o piensas resolver) que pueden haber incompatibilidades entre la versión que colocas y la que la otra librería usa.

Comment: Si de hecho ya lo estoy haciendo con otras librerías (quartz), lo que ocurre es que no se con qué librería tiene el conflicto, por lo que voy a ir a base de prueba y error.